# How to move the content of my Amazon.com cart to an international Amazon website?

Tags: amazon

It happens to me all the time: I follow a link on the web to purchase a book on amazon.com, add the book to my cart, and at the moment I want to checkout I realize I was on amazon.com when I should really have been on (say) amazon.co.uk (the way I realize this is with the stupidly expensive shipping costs and ridiculously long shipping times).

At this time, do I have an easy way to transfer my cart from amazon.com to amazon.co.uk?

So far the best way I found is painful, as it involves text-selecting and copying the titles I have in the amazon.com cart, paste it in the search box in amazon.co.uk and add the items again to the basket. Not quite convenient when you have several items... any better solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you search for a product you'd find a unique ASIN number for every product at the bottom of the product page(ASIN is same for any domain), just use that ASIN number in search box in the domain you prefer, you'll find the product if it is available.

Comment: Useful indeed, but still need to go through all the products one by one. In addition, not all ASINs are available on all domains, and books have an ISBN instead.